# How to display array data in angular

Tags: arrays, angular6

I am new to angular. I have array data. I want to display data on my webpage.

my question is how to print data. the data showing in console.log().

My console.log screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the array in a webpage using `*ngFor` directive of Angular for example -

```
<div *ngFor='let item of arrayName'>
  {{item?.propertyName}}
</div>
```

<kbd>[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrfdum?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)</kbd>

- For more detailed info please refer [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor)

Answer (score 1):

In order to display array on your template you need **[`ngFor`](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data)**

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let measurement of data.measurements">
      {{ measurement }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor='let measurement of ObjectName.measurements'>
    {{ measurement?.label }}
</div>
```

For more info please visit the angular tutorial

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2